# Nesting tcolorbox changes border style

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I have a box with a modified border style, but when I nest two of such boxes, the style of the inner one is not the one that I set. I know, from the doc and from other questions on this stackexchange, that nesting `breakable` boxes can create problem, but I don't remember having read anything about styles.

So my question: how can I nest boxes while preserving the style like if the inner one is not nested ?

[image: An image with two boxes, the first one is displayed properly; the second one contains an other box inside, which does not have the correct stype.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    sharp corners,
    }

\newtcolorbox{sidebox}{
    borderline={1pt}{0pt}{gray!80!cyan},
    colback=gray!80!cyan!5,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidebox}
    \[A=B\]
\end{sidebox}

\begin{sidebox}
\begin{sidebox}
    \[A=B\]
\end{sidebox}
\end{sidebox}
\end{document}
```

---

Notice that, in this MWE, I nest the same kind of box (i.e. a `sidebox` in a `sidebox`), but in practice, it is not necessarily the case, and the box might have been created with `\tcolorboxenvironment`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to read section *4.16 Layered Boxes and Every Box Settings* in `tcolorbox` documentation where relation between layered styles are explained.

With your example, it seems that changing `\tcbset` by `\tcbsetfoereverylayer` works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbsetforeverylayer{
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    sharp corners,
    }

\newtcolorbox{sidebox}{
    borderline={1pt}{0pt}{gray!80!cyan},
    colback=gray!80!cyan!5,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidebox}
    \[A=B\]
\end{sidebox}

\begin{sidebox}
\begin{sidebox}
    \[A=B\]
\end{sidebox}
\end{sidebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Do you know the rationale for why options are not preserved for every layers by default?

Comment: It is discussed in section 4.16 of the documentation of tcolorbox, but no rationale is provided as far as I can tell.